# how to pass password to sudo rootsh

Tags: sudo

I login to my application server using my id. Once logged in I login to the appserver using the generic-id in the following way

```
sudo rootsh -i -u generic-id
```

this prompts me for a password after which i login successfully.

How do I pass the password from a file or plain text something like below

```
echo password | sudo rootsh -i -u generic-id
cat passwordFile | sudo rootsh -i -u generic-id
```

When i try to do the above, i get the error.

> tcsetattr: stdin: Inappropriate ioctl for device

i tried using the command

```
echo password | sudo rootsh -i -u -S generic-id
```

and then i get the error

> Sorry, user xxxid is not allowed to execute '/bin/rootsh -i -u -S
> generic-id' as root on host.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo password | sudo -S rootsh -i -u generic-id
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem. I am now getting this error "SSO Password:tcsetattr: stdin: Inappropriate ioctl for device"

Comment: @SaurabhGhosh Which OS and which version of `sudo` is that?

Comment: OS version is SLES12-SP2 & Sudo version 1.8.10p3
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.10p3
Sudoers file grammar version 43
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.10p3

Comment: @SaurabhGhosh Maybe this is just a misunderstanding and the error message is not from `sudo`. (Configure in `suduers` and then) run `echo password | sudo -S  /bin/echo foo`. Does that work?

Comment: I tried the option {echo "password\n" | sudo -S rootsh -i -u generic-id"} not with the braces, and then i again get the same error i.e. "tcsetattr: stdin: Inappropriate ioctl for device", therefore i don't think its an issue with the sudo. Why do you think its not an error from sudo and what configuration do you suggest in sudo.

Comment: @SaurabhGhosh Please execute `echo "password\n"` in a shell. It does not what you expect. If `sudo` does require a password for that command and even a wrong password gives you the same error message then `sudo` must be the problem because it obviously does not even get to the point of password checking. In general: If someone like me tells you what to do in order to better understand the problem then it is rarely a good idea to ignore that and do instead what you think makes sense. If you were the one with the better ideas then you wouldn't have to ask here, would you?